# Using glm(family = guassian) on data that is actually Poisson. Strange non-symmetrical bias

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, bias

Let's say I want test the consequences of assuming a normally distributed response variable in a glm model when it is really Poisson.

I simulate some data with some quadratic terms.

```
set.seed(1)
N = 1000

x1 = rnorm(N,0,1)
x2 = rnorm(N,0,1)

b1 = 0.2 # I set the linear terms equal but opposite sign
b2 = -0.2

g1 = 0.2 # I also set the quadratic terms equal but opposite sign
g2 = -0.2

# plug these values in as follows...
mu = exp(0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + g1*x1^2 + g2*x2^2 + rnorm(N,0,1))
y = rpois(N, lambda=mu)
fit = glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2), family = gaussian(link = "identity"))

coef(fit) # look at the resulting coefficients

(Intercept)          x1          x2     I(x1^2)     I(x2^2) 
  1.5312231   0.7506879  -0.1288538   0.7601453  -0.3081372
```

Looking at the coefficients, only the positive terms are quite far away from their negative counterparts.

Does anyone have any intuition why? If you run this over and over again with different random seeds, the absolute value of the positive coefficients is consistently larger than the negative ones. I can't really understand why sign would matter so much in this context. Why isn't it symmetrical?

Comment: The question sounds vague for me. Your demonstration is only one situation. Are you claiming this behavior always occurs  for any second-order polynomial ? What about the assumptions on the coefficients ?

Comment: It seems to happen when there is a second-order polynomial. If one uses replicate() in R, it seems to hold up under a range of different values for the coefficients. I am pretty sure it is an artifact. I am just not sure what is wrong with my thinking.

Comment: BTW you do not simulate a true Poisson regression model here, or you drop a predictor variable: the one generating by `rnorm(N,0,1)` when you define `mu`.

Comment: I wanted to add some noise. I took it out. Doesn't seem to help. mu = exp(0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + g1*x1^2 + g2*x2^2)

Comment: Ok, but you claim that a certain result seems to hold under some assumptions and these assumptions are not clear enough to investigate the why.

Comment: Why would you expect symmetry in this situation? You've done several things that might result in asymmetry.

Comment: Specifically, the most likely problem is that your data has an exponential relationship, but you fit a linear one. There's also the normal (fit) vs Poisson (data) thing, but that's more like a second-order effect. From where does your expectation of symmetry arise?